# Why is this <Div class="nav"> ruining my navigations positioning?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, nav

```
<div class="nav">
 <ul id="menu">
   <li><a href="C:\Users\mfzi\Desktop\site\test.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="C:\Users\mfzi\Desktop\site\chat.html">Chat</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

This code shows me this:[image]

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="C:\Users\mfzi\Desktop\site\test.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="C:\Users\mfzi\Desktop\site\chat.html">Chat</a></li>
</ul>
```

This code shows me:[image]

The thing is, I am trying to keep my navigation bar the same through-out every page of this site.. I am unable to do it without using a `<div>`. my CSS is right, because it is working normal on the home page.. just not on the Chat page.

Any ideas?

to clarify, I want my navigation bar to float to the left (which I have set), not boxed together like the first image shows. I want it to be the second image, but I can't do it the way I did it because it will ruin my home page (nav bar will go out of view).

Comment: Need a little more information to be able to tell exactly, but looks like your <div class="nav"></div> may have some positioning CSS applied to it, as well as a width of some sort. I've had good experiences with using Google Chrome's debug tools to inspect a particular element to see what CSS rules may be applying that I didn't intend to. I'd start there.

Comment: you were absolutely correct! Thank you!! I had a div in CSS already specifying the width! Now I gotta create some children

Comment: looks like the `div.nav` has a fixed width so the li's will break until the width is reached